# Java: Override table cell renderer, but with default background and properties

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, jtableheader

If you want to add a custom renderer, normally, you'd either extend some `JComponent` (like `JLabel`) and implement `TableCellRenderer`, or you'd extend `DefaultTableCellRenderer`.  However, in either case, what I find is that the cell style is completely overridden.

What I'd really like is to be able to paint the default L&F background and then paint on top of it using other L&F defaults like foreground color and font.

So, here's what I tried to do.  First, the class:

```
public class IntervalHeaderRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

    private TableCellRenderer delegate;
    private Component component;

    public IntervalHeaderRenderer(TableCellRenderer defaultRenderer)
    {
        this.delegate = defaultRenderer;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                           boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        component = delegate.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        // Maybe override some settings.  
        // You could make the label bold, for instance.

        return component;
        // return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // What I really want to do is paint the original component
        component.paint(g);
        // And then draw on top of it.
    }
}
```

And then I override the cell (header) renderer like this:

```
TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderRenderer(new IntervalHeaderRenderer(renderer));
```

I'm basically just following the suggestions here:  [TableCellRenderer, Part 2 - How To Create A Custom Renderer](http://www.jyloo.com/news/?pubId=1281514002000)

If I return `component`, it renders as if I had overridden nothing.  That is, I get the header with the label I had programmed with the chosen L&F background and style and everything.  **But**, of course, there no way to render my stuff afterwards.

On the other hand, if I return `this`, then I get absolutely nothing.  Mac native L&F gives me a white background, while Nimbus gives me a solid of some other color.

I'm clearly missing something.  Are there other methods on the `Component` that I need to override and forward to the original?  How does the default component get drawn if not by overriding `paint`?  (I've also tried overriding `paintComponent`.  No difference.)

Is there another way to do this?  I've thought about trying to drop a native styled `JPanel` in there and then making a custom (transparent background) component its child, although I'm not sure about how to go about it, and I'm not really sure I'd get the native L&F table **header** background anyhow.  In fact, I highly doubt I'd get the native header style, just the native `JPanel` style.

Basically, I need a custom table header (and separately, the cells too, actually), but I want to avoid messing too much with the native L&F.

Thanks!

Comment: _paint the default L&F background and then paint on top of it using other L&F defaults like foreground color and font._ - if everything is supposed to be the default just use .. the default ;-) As that cant be your intention: what _exactly_ do you want to differ from the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look at the approach taken in `updateUI()` in [`SelectAllHeaderTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137786/how-can-i-put-a-control-in-the-jtableheader-of-a-jtable), as well as the helpful caveats in the accepted answer.

Addendum: By way of explanation, note that the header's appearance falls under the aegis of the host platform's corresponding UI delegate, usually derived from [`TableHeaderUI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/TableHeaderUI.html). You may want to confine your changes to the [*UIManager Defaults*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) common to popular Look & Feel implementations. Also, don't override `paint()`. I would avoid overriding `paintComponent()`; and, if necessary, override `paintIcon()`, as shown in [`TableSorter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableSorterDemoProject/src/components/TableSorter.java).

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'm nearly there.  Based on your suggestion, I now have the correct-looking background.  However, you say not to override paint().  What instead do I need to override in order to paint my custom widget on top of the background? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, using this method, it looks right for Mac native, but not for Nimbus.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html). Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) showing your revised approach.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` source code, there you will see how the default behavior reads the defaults colors like:

```
        fg = DefaultLookup.getColor(this, ui, "Table.dropCellForeground");
        bg = DefaultLookup.getColor(this, ui, "Table.dropCellBackground");
```