# Add Menu item or Menu to JTable column header in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jmenu, jtableheader

Is it possible to add some Menu type (drop down) or a menu item to the column header of JTable in Java swing?

If possible please tell me the approach that I can use.

Comment: See also [How can I put a control in the JTableHeader of a JTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137786/how-can-i-put-a-control-in-the-jtableheader-of-a-jtable)