# how to add a jcheckbox when the table model initially is not defined.

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

how to add a jcheckbox when the table model initially is not defined.

I have populated the jtable with data from database, but now I need to add a jcheckbox used for selection of desired record.

I can add jcheckbox to jtable if the datatable  rows are perdefined with boolean class. But as I am using a database to read from I am bit confused.

any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

[`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) relies on its `TableModel` to determine what to display. Although only existing rows can be shown, you can insert an *uncommitted* row in the model for editing. What and when to commit are entirely up to your application.

As discussed in [*How to Use Tables: Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), the default renderer and editor for a column of type `Boolean` is a `JCheckBox`. Here's a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513) that conditions `getColumnClass()` accordingly. Here's a more complex [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) that defines a composite type, [`Value`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table#Value), as well as a custom renderer and editor.