# JTable getSelectedRow does not return the selected row index

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I try to get data in the row that is selected but `getSelectedRow()` doesn't work. Actually, I used that method in the other class, but it works in there. When I try to print the row index; the prompt shows -1; as not selected.

I tried most of solutions that are on the internet but they didn't solve my solutions.

```
public Canteen() {
    try {
        jbInit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void jbInit() throws Exception {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout( null );
    this.setSize( new Dimension(400, 300) );
    this.setTitle( "CANTEEN" );
    jScrollPane1.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 230, 235));
    jButton1.setText("REFRESH");
    jButton1.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 235, 100, 20));
    jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jButton1_actionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
    jButton2.setText("CLOSE");
    jButton2.setBounds(new Rectangle(120, 235, 110, 20));
    jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jButton2_actionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(jTable1, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jButton2, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jButton1, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, null);
    jTable1 = new JTable (model);

    String header [] = {"CUSTOMER", "PRODUCT", "QUANTITY","ORDER NO"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        model.addColumn(header[i]);
        }  

    //refresh every 1 minute 
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            model.setRowCount(0);
            try {
                Class.forName(driverName);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username, password);
                statement = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT USER_NAME, QUANTITY, PRD_NAME, ORDER_NUMBER FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_NUMBER DESC");
                int count = rs.getRow();
                String user [] = new String [count];
                int i = 0;
                while (rs.next()){
                    String name = rs.getString(1);
                    String prdName = rs.getString(3);
                    int number = rs.getInt(2);
                    int orderNumber = rs.getInt(4);
                    model.insertRow(i,new Object []{name,prdName,number, orderNumber});
                    }
                conn.close();
                }
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException s) {
                            System.out.println("Couldn't find the database driver");
                            System.out.println(s);

                        } 
                        catch (SQLException s) {
                            System.out.println("Couldn't connect to the database\n" +s);
                        }

       }
    },0, 60000); 
    }

private void jButton1_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //set from row 0 for refresh
    model.setRowCount(0);

    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username, password);
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT USER_NAME, QUANTITY, PRD_NAME FROM ORDERS ORDER BY ORDER_NUMBER DESC");
        int count = rs.getRow();
        String user [] = new String [count];
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()){
            String name = rs.getString(1);
            String prdName = rs.getString(3);
            int number = rs.getInt(2);
            model.insertRow(i,new Object []{name,prdName,number});
            } 
        conn.close();
        }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException s) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find the database driver");
            System.out.println(s);

        } 
        catch (SQLException s) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't connect to the database\n" +s);
        }

}

private void jButton2_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(jTable1.getSelectedRow());
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a GUI editor, such as the one in NetBeans?

Comment: I use jDeveloper and oracle SQL developer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look to your code

```
private void jbInit() throws Exception {
    ...
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(jTable1, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jButton2, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jButton1, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, null);
    jTable1 = new JTable (model);
    ...
```

You add `jTable1` to the `JScrollPane` at first and only then you create `jTable1`. It's incorrect way. `jTable1` variable doen't linked now with table you place at the form. I think it's cause of your problem.

Move creation of the `jTable1` before adding in into `JScrollPane`.

```
...
jTable1 = new JTable (model);
jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(jTable1, null);
this.getContentPane().add(jButton2, null);
this.getContentPane().add(jButton1, null);
this.getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, null);
...
```

Comment: Why this using before declaration didn't throw an exception or compile error?

Answer (score 4):

As your other example shows, `getSelectedRow()` does work, so you're going to have to debug your code. Comparison with the [sscce](http://sscce.org/) below may suggest way forward. Both the `ActionListener` and the `ListSelectionListener` show the selected row.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12301923/230513
 */
public class TableSelection extends JPanel {

    private static final String SHOW = "Show";
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction(SHOW) {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());
        }
    });

    public TableSelection() {
        model.addColumn("Column");
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            model.addRow(new Object[]{i});
        }
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(160, 100));
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
            new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    button.setText(SHOW + " " + table.getSelectedRow());
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        table.setRowSelectionInterval(3, 3);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TableSelection");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TableSelection().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: first thank you for your answer but I tried your solution in my class but it didn't work. When I try to get row count, it works perfectly but getSelectedRow() method still doesn't work. Maybe populating my jTable from sql causes this problem. I really don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: In general populating from SQL should not cause this problem. Try replacing the `for` loop in  my example with your query, which should increment `i` or use `addRow()`.