# Fast way to find visible components in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, visibility

Given a `JScrollPane` containing a thousand components using some `LayoutManager`. Each component can be either in a *loaded* or *unloaded* state. There are not enough resources for all to be loaded.

I'd like to have only the visible components `load()`ed in memory, and the invisible components `unload()`ed. When the user scrolls, a listener needs to keep updating the components' states: `unload()` the previously visible, and `load()` the newly visible.

1. At any given moment, how do I know which components are visible?
2. Can I know this without iterating the whole thousand? (as if an efficient `viewPort.getVisibleComponents()`)

I was going to have a prepared sorted list of all component Ys, then in runtime binary search the `ViewPort`'s Y to reach an index which may guide me to the visible ones. This failed as component Ys all returned 0 during list preparation time. This needs to be efficient.

Comment: 1) *"Each component can be either in a loaded or unloaded state. There are not enough resources for all to be loaded."*  Are you certain?  How are you certain?  OOME?  *"This needs to be efficient."*  How long does it take to search a list of thousands of objects?  (I'm guessing 'not long')  2) Why the need to even 'find objects'?  If each has an `Action`, that action will know what to do and should have/be given access to any components (e.g. a progress-bar) that it needs on being created.

Comment: `JTable` scales well in the thousands regime; load the currently selected row in a `ListSelectionListener`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12306104/230513).

Comment: See also this [*Easy, simple to use LRU cache in Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/224868/230513).

Comment: What if you override paintComponent() method for each of the thousand components? hen it's called it's visible.

Comment: @Andrew: Regarding (1) this code will run off a ViewPort changeListener, so yes, any delay is very much felt. (2) The component's Action, namely `load()`, is costly and should only be called for visible components. Calling every component's `load()` defeats the purpose (and will kill resources along the way).

Comment: @trashgod: Regarding (1. Table) I haven't thought of this ... I don't see the connection to any selection-listener, I'm looking for visibility, but maybe its possible on a JTable. Regarding (2 LRU) LRU cache, I think my problem regards more to "who is visible now" and less to the loading ... but if I'm missing your point then can you give me a hint?

Comment: @StanislavL: This is a direction! While it'll only tell me when to `load()`, and not when to `unload()`, it is something to think about...

Answer (score 1):

For concreteness, I will assume 1000's of records, each represented by an instance of `class Record`. Each such `Record` should contain a unique, meaningful `key` of type `Key`.

- Obtain the `List<Key>`, possibly in a background task.
- Construct a one-column [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) of the `key` values.
- Use this model to construct a `JTable`, `table`.
- Add the `table` to a `JScrollPane` on the left side of a suitable layout.
- On the right, add a panel that can `Display` the details of a single, selected `Record`.
- Let `Display` contain a `ListSelectionListener`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12306104/230513), that updates the details for whichever `Record` is currently selected in the `table`.
- Add each selected `Record` to a [cache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/224868/230513), retrieving the `Record` from storage, possibly in a background task, only if not already present in the cache.