# Load JList for cells of 1st column in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist

Is there any way to load `JList` on the first column of `JTable` on click?

The table has zones in the 1st column (with multiple locations in every zone).  I want to show zone locations to the user in a list, on zone click.

I am looking for it from 1 and half day.  I don't want to put my code here because there is a lot of functionality in my table class.

Comment: Basically i have zones in my jTable and when user clicks on zone...there are locations in every zone...i want to show zone's locations to the user in jList.

Comment: then use XxxTableModel from JTable for JList

Comment: if you can show an example it will be great because i am not very good when it comes to swing programming..!!!

Comment: @mKorbel has many [examples dealing with `JTable`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+jtable+jlist&submit=search)  (those are only the ones that also mention `JList`).  ;)  Have a look through them & see if you can make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of *your* best attempt.

Comment: Please review the latest [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13683140/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to add a `ListSelectionListener` to the table, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12306104/230513), and update your `ListModel` according to the row selected. A `JList` listens to its own `ListModel`, so the update should be automatic.

[image]