# Unable to execute a query in MVC framework

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jdbc, jtable

From Class Model:

```
    public TableModel getTableData() {
     TableModel model=null;
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT eventID as 'Event ID', date as 'Date',eventName as 'Name', time as 'Start Time' FROM Event";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        model = (DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));       
        }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   finally {
        try {rs.close(); pst.close();  }
        catch(SQLException e){}     }                                 
       return model; 
}

public void getEvent(String tableClick) {
    Events e = new Events();
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Event WHERE eventID='"+tableClick+"' ");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){      
        e.setEventName(rs.getString(2));
        e.setEventDate(rs.getDate(3));
        e.setEventTime(rs.getString(4));
        e.setEventVenue(rs.getString(5));
        e.setEventDetail(rs.getString(6));
        e.setEventOpportunity(rs.getString(7));
        e.setEventMoreDetails(rs.getString(8));
        e.setEndTime(rs.getString(9));
       }
    } 
    catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
        rs.close();pst.close();conn.close();} 
        catch (Exception ex){}
      }
} //end getEvent
```

From Class Controller:

```
@Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        int rowSelected = view.tableEvent.getSelectedRow();
        String tableClick = view.tableEvent.getModel().getValueAt(view.tableEvent.convertRowIndexToModel(rowSelected), 0).toString();
        model.getEvent(tableClick); //tell model to change its state based on user input on views - model is instance of class model
    }
```

When I run my program I have stacktrace showing error at line `pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Event WHERE eventID='"+tableClick+"' ");` of the Model Class, and line `model.getEvent(tableClick);` of the Controller class. Having run the programme with break points in debug mode in NetbeanIDE, I can see only the `e.setEventName(...)` being populated with a value from database, while all other values of the `Event` bean  class are null. `e.setEventDate(...)` sets date as #2222. If you need further information I will edit my post. but this is really bugging me.

Is it the ListSelectionListener causing problem, perhaps `mouseListener` more appropriate?

to further add, if I change the `getEvent()` to

```
public void getEvent(String tableClick) {
Events e = new Events();
try {
    pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Event WHERE eventID='"+tableClick+"' ");
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){      
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yess");

   }
}
```

it only executed displays `Yes` the first time a row is clicked. Not on the second click on another row.

Answer (score 1):

Use MouseListener to detect clicked table row.

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent event) {
  int rowSelected = view.tableEvent.rowAtPoint(event.getPoint());
  String tableClick = view.tableEvent.getModel().getValueAt(view.tableEvent.convertRowIndexToModel(rowSelected), 0).toString();
  model.getEvent(tableClick); //tell model to change its state based on user input on views*/
```

Also  `rs.close();pst.close();` is to be end of `try` block of the method getEvent().

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12306104/230513), to detect a *change* in the selection. Use a `JButton` and a [`CellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513), to invoke an action for a particular row.