# Get position of Click JTable while using Cell renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

I'm currently using a JTable in Java to display a large amount of text information,  and as such have implemented text wrapping, using the following code:

```
MyCellRenderer mcr = new MyCellRenderer();
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(mcr);

class MyCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
  public MyCellRenderer() {
setLineWrap(true);
setWrapStyleWord(true);

 }

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object
    value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
setText(value.toString());
setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),
        getPreferredSize().height);
if (table.getRowHeight(row) != getPreferredSize().height) {
        table.setRowHeight(row, getPreferredSize().height);
}
return this;
}
}
```

However, when this is implemented, any attempt to detect the cell which is clicked, simply returns "-1" (out of bounds) as the point of click, I am using the following code to detect the click location:

```
table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {

  public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    int row = table.rowAtPoint( e.getPoint() );
    int column = table.columnAtPoint( e.getPoint() );
  }
});
}
```

Is there any way, whilst maintaining the text wrapping, that I can text the cell which is clicked in the JTable?

Comment: `table.addMouseListener(..` Use [`table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(ListSelectionListener)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#addListSelectionListener-javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener-) instead to make life much simpler.  *"I'm currently using a JTable in Java to display a large amount of text information"* That's really not what a table component is designed for, or particularly good at..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Agreed, but my current situation requires a large amount of text information to be displayed next to it's relevant data, using a row from a JTable seemed a relevant option.

Comment: Your code doesnt wrap fields to me: http://pastebin.com/ARLvN3bR

Comment: There is also an additional section where you apply the wrapper to the model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My current situation requires a large amount of text information to be displayed next to [the] relevant data

Instead of a `MouseListener`, add a [`TableModelListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html) to your `TableModel` and update the `Document` model of an adjacent [`JTextComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html). In this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513), the `TableModelListener` updates the `ListModel` of an adjacent `JList`.

Alternatively, add a [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to your table's `ListSelectionModel` and update an adjacent component accordingly. In this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12306104/230513) using `SINGLE_SELECTION`, the `ListSelectionListener` updates an adjacent `JButton`.

Alternatively, look at this [`TablePopupEditor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513), which uses a `JButton` as a `TableCellEditor`. The button's `ActionListener` evokes a popup modal  `JDialog` containing a `JTextArea`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives the above functionality, (it ignores all wrapping cell renderers)
        table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {

```
  public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
    int row = target.getSelectedRow();
    int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
    if((row >=0) && (column >=0)){
      //Stuff
    }

  }
});
```