# Handling button event in main class

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jdialog

I'm new to Java and programming. I want to generate an `int` in a `JDialog` class by selecting a row in a table and send that `int` to the main class which created it, or, to handle the button action performed in the main class. Main class creates the subclass here:

```
private void launchtable() {
    DlgBeds dcl = new DlgBeds();
    dcl.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    dcl.setVisible(true);

    // I want in this place to put something like this:
    txtCode.setText(subclassgeneratedint );
}
```

But first I need to get that int from the subclass., I tried creating a method there that I can use in main to return the `int`, but it instead sets the text with the first row selected (the default selection), and it can't return more row selections to keep changing `txtCode`; the method like just dies there.
The main could also have an `action performed` for the button in the subclass but the parameter would need to be one from the subclass I guess.

```
protected void actionPerformed[button in the subclass](ActionEvent e) {
    //actions
}
```

I'm really lost, I know I need to study more to solve situations like this but I needed the answer as fast as possible.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to your table. You can get the selected row as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12306104/230513) and pass it to your main window using a `PropertyChangeListener` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513).