# Filter a JTable by column rather than row in Java

Tags: java, jtable, jtextfield, rowfilter, tablecolumn

Is there any implementation in place in Java to filter a JTable (using a search JTextField) by its column (header value) rather than its row? I need columns to show/hide according to the string found when searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it working like this:

Declare some global variable for a temporary table and table model to hold the hidden columns:

```
private JTable hiddenTable = new JTable();
private DefaultTableColumnModel hiddenModel = new DefaultTableColumnModel();
```

Then use a filter method for every key pressed to add the columns to hide to the temporary table model while removing them from the main table model. You then show them again when the string matches by adding them back to the main table, and removing them from the temporary one:

```
private void filterList() {

        // Hide columns
        for (TableColumn column : table.getColumns()) {
            if (!((String) column.getHeaderValue()).toLowerCase().contains(
                    searchBox.getText().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                hiddenModel.addColumn(column);
                table.getColumnModel().removeColumn(column);
            }
        }

        // Show columns
        for (TableColumn column : hiddenTable.getColumns()) {
            if (((String) column.getHeaderValue()).toLowerCase().contains(
                    searchBox.getText().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                table.getColumnModel().addColumn(column);
                hiddenModel.removeColumn(column);
            }
        }
    }
```

The only problem here is that the columns lose their order when added back into the table.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any implementation in place in Java to filter a JTable (using a search JTextField) by its column (header value) rather than its row?

- yes have look at [RowFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) and apply to required column

> I need columns to show/hide according to the string found when searching.

- not an easy job, because it requires a lot of effort, and excellent knowledge about `Java Essential classes`, `Swing` and being an expert with `JTable`
- I wouldn't go this way, use proper `ColumnRender`, then Column should be highlighted, instead of jumping (hide --> show ---> hide etc.) of `JTables Column` on the screen
- there are some examples about `RowFilter`, `RowSorter`, never needed that, never tried.

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7137786/230513) on responding to table header clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) implementation that wraps your real model to do the filtering. Just keep notifying the TableModelListeners whenever the columns change.