# JTable in JScrollPane: Detect if mouse is over table header

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable in a JScrollPane. When the user is at the top of the table, eg. row 0 is displayed and above it the table header `tableHeader.contains(p);` is `true`.

When the user scroll down and say row 10 is now the top row, if the mouse is over the table header and the table header changes its look due to that, `tableHeader.contains(p);` is `false` in all cases.

How can I detect that the mouse cursor is over the header when the top row is not row 0?

Comment: How can I detect that the mouse cursor is over the header when the top row is not row 0?, please how to corresponding words from 1st and 2nd part together, can be miss_spelled as non_sence, edit your question here with better description

Comment: post an SSCCE short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTables view in local variable, maybe is issue somewhere, not only as is described in (partial) answer by @Sam here

Comment: A complete example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7137786/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(...)
```

to add a MouseListener to the table header. The MouseListener has a method

```
mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
```

in which you can put the code you want to be executed when the cursor is over the table header.