# Add component to columnheader of scrollpane that contains a jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

The jlabel isn't shown, because the panel isn't in the column header. I've no idea whats wrong, here is my code:

```
JScrollPane scrollpane_1 = new JScrollPane();
JTable table = new JTable(); //has 4 columns
JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
panel_1.add(new JLabel("Test"));
scrollpane_1.setViewportView(table);
scrollpane_1.setColumnView(panel_1);
```

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7137786/230513)?

Comment: `has 4 columns` - no it doesn't. You just created an empty table. Until you add a TableModel to the table it has no data an no columns. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem.