# Jtable get column header component

Tags: java, swing, jtable, components

I was wondering if any of you knows a good method to get the actual JComponent instance rendering a column header in an existing JTable.

Could not find anything helpful on google, so I came here. :)

I already know that there is a TableCellRenderer interface which delivers the component I want to get, but there is no guarantee that it'll return the same instance every time, so it is more or less useless to me.

**Edit:**

The goal is to have a possibility to get the Location and size of the component representing a column header dynamically.

And by column header component I mean the instance of the following object:

[image]

I really can't post any useful code example, sorry.
Actually any JTable example will do, as the problem refers to the standard Java JTable functionality.

Comment: What's your actual problem? What do you want achieve? post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: *The goal is to have a possibility to get the Location and size of the component representing a column header dynamically.* Ok, but why? What do you want/need to do with this component?

Comment: I need those values (Location, Size) for the ability to create a component which will imitate those two properties.

Those components then have no size or location, instead they delegate any calls to the components they are imitating.
I need for some masking features on our GUI.

Comment: Here's one way to [*put a control in the* `JTableHeader` *of a* `JTable`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7137786/230513).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Rectangle r = table.getTableHeader().getHeaderRect(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).getHeaderRenderer()` what you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, getHeaderRenderer() returns on an Object implementing the TableCellRenderer interface, it is not a Component instance itself (at least not necessarily). Also according to Javadoc this method will return null if default header renderer is used.

Comment: Indeed, in that case the `table.getHeader().getDefaultRenderer()` is used.
If you want to use some attributes from the component, then you might find `table.getTableHeader().getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(i)` useful. But I don't think anything stops the JTable to create a new component on each render if a non-default renderer is used.

Comment: As it seems there is no clean way to get that properties.
I'll have to live with that :)
Anyway thanks to you all for your effort.