# How to make a specific combox like the one in web?

Tags: java, swing, layout, combobox

I want to know how can i make a swing comboBox like this one:

Actually i got this one from web framework like jquery and html but in swing can we make a multiselect combobox like this?

Comment: Yes, we can. But, what have you tried already?

Comment: no idea i'm using just combbox is there any third party lib to do something like that in swing?

Comment: Using `JCombobox` is the right direction. :) You need to align them with a proper layout like `BoxLayout`. It's not very hard.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to create your own custom component; there isn't going to be a magical out-of-the-box solution.

You do this be extending an existing component, or by creating a class that combines multiple components. In this case you might create a JPanel that holds both a JComboBox and a JPanel, and that JPanel would hold your JCheckBoxes.

Comment: An example using `JTable` is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513).