# Swing Outline with Checkbox in node column

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, jxtreetable, jtreetable

I am creating an JOutline that has rooms, and inside each room has multiple products. You can select an individual product and hit details, but I also need to be able to select check boxes next to multiple products using a checkbox.

I am particularly looking for a way to have the checkbox on the far left of the objects.

Is there any way to do this, or am I better of looking into JXTreeTable?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692), [`Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html) requires your implementation of the [`RowModel`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/RowModel.html) interface, which should be passed to your [`OutlineModel`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/OutlineModel.html) constructor.

```
class MyRowModel implements RowModel {…}
TreeModel myModel = new MyTreeModel(…);
OutlineModel outlineModel = DefaultOutlineModel.createOutlineModel(
    myModel, new MyRowModel(), …);
Outline outline = new Outline();
outline.setModel(outlineModel);
```

In your implementation of `RowModel`, follow the familiar `JTable` [edit/render scheme](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for a model value of type `Boolean`:

- The `getColumnClass()` implementation should return `Boolean.class` for the relevant column.
- The  `isCellEditable()` implementation should return `true` for the relevant column.
- The `getColumnClass()` implementation should return the value from the given node in `myModel`.
- The `setValueFor()` implementation should update the given node, so the renderer will see the new value when editing concludes.

[image]

Comment: I actually have it functioning as you've shown above, but I am looking for a way to have the checkbox in the node column, I feel like I need to make a custom Outline that can take a checkbox component in the RenderDataProvider

Comment: AFAIK, only `RowModel` decorations are supported.

Comment: This was my fear, but I wanted to make sure, thank you for your time.

Comment: If you want to check whole subtrees, you can handle it in the model, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513).