# Placing components on top of a header of JTable

Tags: java, swing

I want to place `Components` like `JLabel`, `JTextField` on specific location, my application view hierarchy looks like this :

```
| frame
| ---- tabbedPane
     | ---- Panel             (BorderLayout)
           | ---- JLabel
           | ---- JScrollPane [center]
                 | ---- JTable
           | ---- JLabel
```

And I need to have something where the top of the header can have a component like that :

[image: What I want]

The problem is that the window can be resized.

Ideas I had, creating an other table on top with no header and manage to stick it to the `JTable`. A part from that I have not a single clue to where I can begin since `LayoutManager` is a pain for me.

Comment: there are three ways to GlassPane, JViewport, or add (standard way) JComponent (GridBagLayout, SpringLayout, BoxLayout), a few times about that here

Comment: Thank you @mKorbel for your response. Can you be more specific on your answer on the GlassPane and the JViewport please ? I don't see where you want to go exactly.

Comment: See [*How to Use Root Panes: The Glass Pane*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html), [*How to Use Scroll Panes: Providing Custom Decorations*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#decorations) and [*A Visual Guide to Layout Managers*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), respectively.

Comment: Thanks @trashgod for the vocabulary and links

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a TableCellRenderer

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender

See the luca's answer in this post

[How can I put a control in the JTableHeader of a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137786/how-can-i-put-a-control-in-the-jtableheader-of-a-jtable)

Comment: Good links, but I think @Totem wants the component(s) _atop_ the header rather than _within_ it.

Comment: Yeah exactly @trashgod, but still thanks reos for proposal