# how to use select all option in checklistbox in swing java?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, checkbox, jfilechooser

In my snippet code! "checkBoxList" has no of files that are chosen by a file chooser and stored in it

check box "tmp" it has checkboxes for the files!

When i display the files[checkboxlist] in my panel.It comes as unchecked!
After I have the option for tick/untick it.

I have the below code for select/unselect option

I need to know when I display the files!The files should display with checked(tick)
Then I can modify which I can tick/untick.

I stuck on this logic!

[

EDIT: I did and updated answer for this part(see the image).

I Add select/deselectall to the panel(box) and it worked

```
box.add(chckbxSelectAll);
```

&& I need&curious to know how  to put my selectall checkbox inside my panel

]

```
public void selectAllMethod() {
Iterator<JCheckBox> i = checkBoxList.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    JCheckBox tmp = i.next();
        if (chckbxSelectAll.isSelected()) {
            tmp.doClick();
        } else {
            tmp.setSelected(false);
            selectedCounter -= 1;
            if (selectedCounter < 0) {
                selectedCounter = 0;
            }
    noOfFileTxt.setText(Integer.toString(selectedCounter));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my button selection method for choosing folder and displaying it in a panel with check box

```
public void chooseDirectoryFrom() {
    String tempStr = null;
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        Font font = new Font("Latha", Font.ITALIC, 10);
        fileChooser.setFont(new Font("Latha", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        fileChooser.setFont(font);

        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            tempStr = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath();
        }
        if (tempStr != null && !tempStr.trim().equals("")) {
            searchBox.setText(tempStr);
            // Enable the search button
        //  btnDisplay.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //btnDisplay.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//  public void selectToDisplay() {            //disabled btn to display
    File sourceFolder = null;
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    if (boxList.size() != 0) {
        middlePanel.remove(scrollPane);
        middlePanel.repaint();
        frame.repaint();
        boxList = new ArrayList<Box>();
        checkBoxList = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
        fileNamesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        selectedCounter = 0;
        noOfFileTxt.setText(Integer.toString(selectedCounter));
    }
    sourceFolder = new File(searchBox.getText());
    File[] sourceFilesList = sourceFolder.listFiles();
    JCheckBox cb1 = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceFilesList.length; i++) {
        if (sourceFilesList[i].isFile() & sourceFilesList[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            fileNamesMap.put(sourceFilesList[i].getAbsolutePath(), sourceFilesList[i].getName());
            cb1 = new JCheckBox(sourceFilesList[i].getAbsolutePath()); 
            cb1.setFont(new Font("Latha", Font.BOLD, 20));
            box.add(cb1);
            checkBoxList.add(cb1);
            cb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).isSelected()) {
                        selectedCounter += 1;
                    } else {
                        selectedCounter -= 1;
                        if (selectedCounter < 0) {
                            selectedCounter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    noOfFileTxt.setText(Integer.toString(selectedCounter));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    boxList.add(box);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(box);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1050, 350));
   scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
   middlePanel.add ( scrollPane );
   frame.getContentPane().add(middlePanel);
   frame.repaint();
  frame.revalidate();
}
```

Here is my image(without selection)!When i load the files in the panel
[image]

Comment: A compete example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513).

Comment: Just set it to selected when you load the file? Explain better what you have and what you are trying to get, ask for someone to help you with the language if needed.

Comment: Yeah to set selected when I load the files @user1803551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

Add checkbox set selected inside the for loop and 
outside the checkbox action listener So that it will perform setselected method!.

```
 cb1.setSelected(!cb1.isSelected());
             selectedCounter += 1;
             noOfFileTxt.setText(Integer.toString(selectedCounter));



selectedCounter += 1; will display the ticked count to the textfield(noOfFileTxt)
```

Thank you :)