# JTableheader with checkable and sortable column

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable where headers are sortable, Below is the code that I have used:

```
TableRowSorter<FolderModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<FolderModel>(folderModel);
setRowSorter(sorter);
```

One column header has a checkbox, rendered with a custom renderer, to check and uncheck all the column values.

I have to choose a different gesture to distinguish between check/uncheck and sorting. I think a single click to sort and a double click to check/uncheck, but the problem is that also a double click fires sorting. What solution is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How can I put a control in the JTableHeader of a JTable?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7137786/230513) Have you tried any of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29963916/230513)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to trashgod I realized that it's a bad idea trying to overload an header column with a checkbox when the headers are sortable too. It's better to put the checkbox outside the table.