# How to create the JTable headers cells with Label (Header Name) and a DropDown?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

Basically I'm trying to show the data in a `JTable`, and to sort the data which am showing, and for the user I want to add a drop down (with header name which is a label) to each of the header cell like we see in excel.

Any idea on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Didn't missed anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I put a control in the JTableHeader of a JTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137786/how-can-i-put-a-control-in-the-jtableheader-of-a-jtable)