# How to make a checkbox with a selection of all checkboxes in the tableview on JavaFX and FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

[image: UsersApp]

Hello everyone. Faced such a problem. It is necessary when clicking the checkbox, which is on top, toggle the checkboxes in the box next to the entire list in the table. And then when you click on the button, delete the selected records, delete the selected records from the MySQL database.

Here is what was done.

**PersonUnpersonValueFactoryController.java**

```
package usersapp.controller;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import usersapp.model.Person;

public class PersonUnpersonValueFactory implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, CheckBox>, ObservableValue<CheckBox>> {

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<CheckBox> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, CheckBox> param) {
        Person person = param.getValue();
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.selectedProperty().setValue(person.isUnperson());

        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> {
            person.setUnperson(new_val);
            System.out.println(new_val);
        });
        return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(checkBox);
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {

private Boolean unperson;

    ...

    //unperson
    public Boolean isUnperson() {
        return this.unperson;
    }

    public void setUnperson(Boolean unperson){
        this.unperson = unperson;
    }

    ...

}
```

**PersonView.fxml**

```
<?import usersapp.controller.PersonUnpersonValueFactory?>

...

<TableView fx:id="personTable" editable="true" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="53.0" prefHeight="285.0" prefWidth="378.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="7.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="7.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="53.0">
                     <columns>
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-alignment: CENTER;">
                           <cellValueFactory>
                              <PersonUnpersonValueFactory />
                           </cellValueFactory>
                           <graphic>
                              <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" />
                           </graphic>
                        </TableColumn>
                        ...
                     </columns>
                  </TableView>
```

I would be very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would just need a listener on the "master" `CheckBox` to watch the `selectedProperty` for changed.  Then you could use that to iterate through the `TableView` items and update their `selectedProperty` as well.

> Note that with the limited code you've provided, I need to make some assumptions on how your data model is constructed.

```
checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

    // Loop through entire TableView to set the selected property for each Item
    for (Item item : tableView.getItems()) {
        item.setSelected(newValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If you want to see the full code, you can look at my GitHub. My project is here https://github.com/SequelONE/UsersApp

Comment: Item item is a model as Person?

Comment: In this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513), `ModelHandler` illustrates a way to condition the header control as the model is updated.

Comment: @AndrejKopp - Not necessarily. You would need to adapt this answer to your own model since you did not include enough of your code in the question. Links to GitHub code are no good at SO, I'm afraid. Please see how to create a [mcve] for your question.